# Can Java generic merges 2 lists of different sub-class into one list of super class?

Tags: java, generics

Say I have Animal class and Cat and Dog as its 2 subclass.

I want to return a list of both pets in one java method. So I tried the following:

```
public List<? extends Animal> getAllPets(...) {
    List<? extends Animal> allDogs = findAnimals(...someOtherArgs, Dog.class);
    List<? extends Animal> allCats = findAnimals(...someOtherArgs, Cat.class);
    List<? extends Animal> retObjs = allDogs;
    retObjs.addAll(allCats); // won't compile
    return retObjs;
}
```

Is it possible to do that in Java?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: retObjs should be a List<Animal>. And it should not be the same list as allDogs: you can't store cats into a list of dogs.

Comment: Okay, sorry for not put this clear. I change the original code to closer to my real code (I use a LDAP api to search things from AD and need return Group and User in a single method.)

Comment: @Jens the compiler output is in Chinese, and it says something like "parameter unmatch"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try such way:

```
public List<? extends Animal> getAllPets(...) {
    List<Dog> allDogs = findDogs();
    List<Cat> allCats = findCats();
    List<Animal> retObjs = new ArrayList<>(allDogs.size() + allCats.size());
    retObjs.addAll(allDogs);
    retObjs.addAll(allCats);
    return retObjs;
}
```

Comment: Votes for those who deserve them ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Simply leave out the wildcard, like this:

```
List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1);
List<Double>  b = Arrays.asList(1.0);
List<Number> c = new ArrayList<>();
c.addAll(a);
c.addAll(b);
System.out.println(c);
```

The above compiles and runs fine, and prints

> [1, 1.0]

Comment: my code has some constrains from doing this. please see my updated code.

Comment: Looks like you got your answer in the meantime. Glad it turned out that quickly. It is always nice to see when answers get accepted quickly, even when it is not mine ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism allows you to store all instances of any child classes in a `List` which was declared as list to store object of `BaseClass`. So, in your case, you need to declare `List<Animal>`, now you can store here any `Cat` or `Dog`.

Answer (score 0):

It's no need to use `?` in your code. Delete them as the code below:

```
public List<? extends Animal> getAllPets(...) {
List<Animal> allDogs = findDogs();
List<Animal> allCats = findCats();
List<Animal> retObjs = allDogs;
retObjs.addAll(allCats); // won't compile
return retObjs;
```

}